# VMWare Workstation Pro can't run on Windows

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, compatibility, vmware-workstation

[image: I]

I got this when I was trying to start 15.5.0 Version of VMware Workstation after updating it and also got same message after downgrading version to 15.0.2 .

I tried to use it in different compatibility mode but It's not fixed.

Comment: this is [caused by last cumulative Windows 10 updates](https://borncity.com/win/2019/10/03/windows-10-update-kb4522015-breaks-vmware-workstation/) for Vmware 12. rename vmware exe as a workaround and make sure all traces of vmware 12 are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this :

1. Uninstall windows updates and block them from reinstalling using "Show or hide troubleshooter". This tool can be downloaded from microsoft official website.
2. Install ADK and use compatibility administrator to "Disable entry" for vmware.exe.

source :

http://mauricemuteti.info/solved-vmware-workstation-14-1-7-12-5-9-15-5-pro-cant-run-on-windows-version-1903-update-problem-fixed/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOzD-G_gy9I

Comment: VMware Pro version 12 here: Disabling completely the VMware Pro entry in the Windows compatibility database (option 2 in the post above) worked very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the Windows ADK at https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install and check your windows version to download correct version. Run adksetup as administrator, be sure 'Application Compability Tools' is selected and upgrade.

Search > Compability Administrator (run as administrator) > Sytem Database(xx-bit) > Applications > VMware Workstation Pro > vmplayer.exe right click 'Enable entry'. (do both vmplayer.exe)

Hope helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy way :

1- Go to Vmware folder under c/Program Files/VMware/VMware Workstation

2- rename the vmware.exe to something else

Answer (score 0):

Install vmware workstation 16.the problem has resolved